# Export Program that references files on my computer

Tags: java, file, export

So here is my program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class cardsAgainstHumanity
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int again = 1;
    String blank1 = "";
    String blank2 = "";
    int playerOneScore = 0;
    int playerTwoScore = 0;
    String playerOneCard = "";
    String playerTwoCard = "";
    String[] oneHand = new String[10];
    String[] twoHand = new String[10];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1 = Vanilla \n2 = Rando Cardrissian \n3 = God Is Dead \nInput Game Type (using those numbers) \nJust a note, players hands reset after each round.");
    String gameMode = input.nextLine();
    Scanner whiteScanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/William/Documents/CardsAgainstHumanityWhite.txt"));
    whiteScanner.useDelimiter("<>");
    Scanner blackScanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/William/Documents/CardsAgainstHumanityBlack.txt"));
    blackScanner.useDelimiter("<>");
    int whitecount = 0;
    int blackcount = 0;
    String[] whiteCardsArray = new String[538];
    String[] blackCardsArray = new String[92];
    //Inputing cards into array
    while(whitecount<=537)
    {
      whiteCardsArray[whitecount]=whiteScanner.next();
      whitecount++;
    }
    while(blackcount<92)
    {
      blackCardsArray[blackcount]=blackScanner.next();
      blackcount++;
    }
    //Keeps going and asking questions until again = 0 (meaning they dont want to play again)
    while(again == 1)
    {
      //Asking player One
      String currentQuestion = blackCardsArray[rand.nextInt(91)+0];
      System.out.println("This is the question: " + currentQuestion);
      System.out.println("Player Two look away, Player One hit enter to see your cards.");
      blank1 = input1.nextLine();
      System.out.println("These are player ones cards: ");
      for(int x = 0; x<10; x++)
      {
        String tmpWhiteString = whiteCardsArray[rand.nextInt(537)+0];
        oneHand[x] = tmpWhiteString;
        System.out.println((x+1)+":" + " " + oneHand[x]);
      }
      System.out.println("Please select your card");
      playerOneCard = oneHand[(input.nextInt())-1];
      //Asking player Two
      System.out.println("Player One look away, Player Two hit enter to see your cards.");
      blank2 = input2.nextLine();
      System.out.println("This is the question: " + currentQuestion);
      System.out.println("These are player twos cards: ");
      for(int x = 0; x<10; x++)
      {
        String tmpWhiteString = whiteCardsArray[rand.nextInt(537)+0];
        twoHand[x] = tmpWhiteString;
        System.out.println((x+1)+":" + " " + twoHand[x]);
      }
      System.out.println("Please select your card");
      playerTwoCard = twoHand[(input.nextInt())-1];
      //Tallying Score
      System.out.println("Player one selected: " + playerOneCard);
      System.out.println("Player two selected: " + playerTwoCard);
      System.out.println("The question was: " + currentQuestion);
      System.out.println("Who won?");
      if(input.nextInt() == 1) playerOneScore++;
      else if(input.nextInt() == 2) playerTwoScore++;
      System.out.println("Player Ones score is: " + playerOneScore);
      System.out.println("Player Twos score is: " + playerTwoScore);
      //play another?
      System.out.println("Would you like to play another round? (1 for yes, 0 for no)");
      again = input.nextInt();
    }
    if(playerOneScore>playerTwoScore)
    {
      System.out.println("Player One wins with " + playerOneScore + " points.");
      System.out.println("Player Two has " + playerTwoScore + " points");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Player Two wins with " + playerTwoScore + " points.");
      System.out.println("Player One has " + playerOneScore + " points");
    }
  }
}
```

As you may be able to tell it is a cards against humanity program. I am referencing two files that have the different cards delineated by <>. So white cards are in one file and black cards are in another.

As you can see the program references these files. How can I export the program but still have it work? (P.S. I am a beginner so I have never exported before).
I will be changing this into a form that opens up a basic UI but I just have the basics for now.

Thanks so much in advance,
William

Comment: What do you mean by "export the program?"

Comment: As like .java file or something. I actually don't know how it works. But cant you package it as some sort of executable program.

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-JAR-File

Comment: Or a JAR file I mean

Comment: It's called an installer.  Generally, when you provide an installer, you also provide any and all files that the application requires.  As I'm not a Java developer, I don't know the first thing about Java installations, though I do know vaguely what a JAR file is.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm assuming you want to export your program as a JAR. This method will allow you to do this.

Just put the files in your compiled programs folder (typically `/bin`; if you're in Eclipse, you can put them in `/src` and have them copied over automatically).

Then get your scanner by using:

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream
     ("Where you kept the file (the root is the bin folder)"));
```